# Datadog Wildfly collection produces error: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Parameter 'name' may not be null

Tags: wildfly, datadog

I want to configure Wildfly metrics collection using Datadog.

I am able to connect the agent and upload data to Datadog servers.
I am able to collect general information and I also see the info in Datadog web UI.
Now I am trying to collect metrics from Wildfly.
Content of `/etc/datadog-agent/conf.d/jboss_wildfly.d/conf.yml` file:

```
init_config:

    is_jmx: true
    collect_default_metrics: true
    new_gc_metrics: true
    service_check_prefix: wildfly

instances:

  - jmx_url: service:jmx:remote+http://localhost:9990
    tools_jar_path: /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.372.b07-2.el9.x86_64/lib/jconsole.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.372.b07-2.el9.x86_64/lib/tools.jar:/opt/wildfly/bin/client/jboss-cli-client.jar
    name: konor1c
```

It produces following errors in Datadog log file:

```
2023-09-26 08:23:51 CEST | JMX | INFO | App | update is in order - updating timestamp: 1695709431
2023-09-26 08:23:51 CEST | JMX | INFO | App | Reinitializing...
2023-09-26 08:23:51 CEST | JMX | INFO | App | Cleaning up instances...
2023-09-26 08:23:51 CEST | JMX | INFO | InstanceCleanupTask | Trying to cleanup: konor1c
2023-09-26 08:23:51 CEST | JMX | INFO | App | Dealing with YAML config instances...
2023-09-26 08:23:51 CEST | JMX | INFO | App | Dealing with Auto-Config instances collected...
2023-09-26 08:23:51 CEST | JMX | INFO | App | Instantiating instance for: jboss_wildfly
2023-09-26 08:23:51 CEST | JMX | INFO | App | Started instance initialization...
2023-09-26 08:23:51 CEST | JMX | INFO | Instance | Trying to connect to JMX Server at konor1c
2023-09-26 08:23:51 CEST | JMX | INFO | Instance | Connection closed or does not exist. Attempting to create a new connection...
2023-09-26 08:23:51 CEST | JMX | INFO | ConnectionFactory | Connecting using JMX Remote
2023-09-26 08:23:51 CEST | JMX | INFO | Connection | Connecting to: service:jmx:remote+http://localhost:9990
2023-09-26 08:23:51 CEST | JMX | INFO | App | Completed instance initialization...
2023-09-26 08:23:51 CEST | JMX | WARN | App | Could not initialize instance: konor1c:
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Parameter 'name' may not be null
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(FutureTask.java:122)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:192)
        at org.datadog.jmxfetch.App.processRecoveryResults(App.java:953)
        at org.datadog.jmxfetch.App$5.invoke(App.java:927)
        at org.datadog.jmxfetch.tasks.TaskProcessor.processTasks(TaskProcessor.java:63)
        at org.datadog.jmxfetch.App.init(App.java:917)
        at org.datadog.jmxfetch.App.start(App.java:403)
        at org.datadog.jmxfetch.App.run(App.java:173)
        at org.datadog.jmxfetch.JmxFetch.main(JmxFetch.java:57)
        at org.datadog.jmxfetch.App.main(App.java:91)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Parameter 'name' may not be null
        at org.wildfly.common.Assert.checkNotNullParamChecked(Assert.java:71)
        at org.wildfly.common.Assert.checkNotNullParam(Assert.java:49)
        at org.wildfly.security.auth.client.AuthenticationConfiguration.useName(AuthenticationConfiguration.java:691)
        at org.jboss.remotingjmx.RemotingConnector.internalRemotingConnect(RemotingConnector.java:247)
        at org.jboss.remotingjmx.RemotingConnector.internalConnect(RemotingConnector.java:156)
        at org.jboss.remotingjmx.RemotingConnector.connect(RemotingConnector.java:103)
        at javax.management.remote.JMXConnectorFactory.connect(JMXConnectorFactory.java:270)
        at org.datadog.jmxfetch.Connection.createConnection(Connection.java:63)
        at org.datadog.jmxfetch.RemoteConnection.<init>(RemoteConnection.java:101)
        at org.datadog.jmxfetch.ConnectionFactory.createConnection(ConnectionFactory.java:38)
        at org.datadog.jmxfetch.Instance.getConnection(Instance.java:405)
        at org.datadog.jmxfetch.Instance.init(Instance.java:418)
        at org.datadog.jmxfetch.InstanceInitializingTask.call(InstanceInitializingTask.java:15)
        at org.datadog.jmxfetch.InstanceInitializingTask.call(InstanceInitializingTask.java:3)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:750)

2023-09-26 08:23:51 CEST | JMX | WARN | App | Unable to instantiate or initialize instance konor1c for an unknown reason.Parameter 'name' may not be null
2023-09-26 08:23:51 CEST | JMX | WARN | App | No instance could be initiated. Retrying initialization.
2023-09-26 08:23:51 CEST | JMX | INFO | App | Found 0 config files
2023-09-26 08:23:51 CEST | JMX | INFO | App | Cleaning up instances...
2023-09-26 08:23:51 CEST | JMX | INFO | InstanceCleanupTask | Trying to cleanup: konor1c
2023-09-26 08:23:51 CEST | JMX | INFO | App | Dealing with YAML config instances...
```

Even if the `name` parameter is set in the YAML config file the error is telling something different.
Is there any other place where the `name` parameter needs to be set to get it work?